# Autoprefixer not adding prefix for IE

Tags: gruntjs, autoprefixer

I'm trying to use Grunt-Autoprefixer in my project but its not adding prefix for IE9 transform `-ms-`
http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

I have IE in my browserlist array `Explorer >= 8`

`browsers: [
                "Android 2.3",
                "Android >= 4",
                "Chrome >= 20",
                "Firefox >= 24",
                "Explorer >= 8",
                "iOS >= 6",
                "Opera >= 12",
                "Safari >= 6"
            ]`

yet, `transform: whatever` becomes

`transform: whatever
 -webkit-transform: whatever`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this one
[postcss/autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers)

Comment: Nice to hear it. I've just started to use it too.

Comment: Neither of these packages worked for me, `-ms-transform` is still not being added.

Comment: Read the article "Disabling" by this reference. I guess autoprefixer: off in your way.